# How can I make mysql only show one time the line if a value is the same?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table looks like this:

```
id   name
1    nice
2    nice
3    nice
4    nicest
5    nicest
```

Having a select statement like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%nice%'` shows all the 5 rows.I am trying to make it only show one time the row if the name is the same.

A select sql that'd show like this after run:

```
id   name
1    nice
4    nicest
```

Comment: `SELECT MIN(id) id, nice FROM tableName WHERE name LIKE '%nice%' GROUP BY name`

Comment: Do you mean you just want to check if a `name` already exists in the database?

Comment: Why `id` 1?  Because it's the smallest number, or are you fine with displaying any id that matches?

Comment: I am fine displaying any id that matches.Also,what I wrote is an example table.I am trying to do that for multiple rows!I am trying to filtrel the names so it only shows them up only one time,not multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the "DISTINCT" command after your "SELECT".

[Source/Use/Example](http://psoug.org/definition/DISTINCT.htm)

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT min(id) AS id,
       name
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  name LIKE '%nice%'
GROUP  BY name
```

Comment: @user2719045 - So there must only be one matching distinct value then.